# Alternative to swiftmailer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I have an issue with [using swiftmailer with the client's SMTP microsoft exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280281/cakeemail-in-cakephp-2-can-send-email-to-the-same-smtp-but-not-swiftmailer-in-la).

To troubleshoot, I am thinking of changing out the swiftmailer with something else.

My entire setup is on an internal network. So no mailgun or sendgrid at all.

How do I use an alternative library for swiftmailer in Laravel in order to troubleshoot?

Also this is the log I get when I tried to use swiftmailer on Laravel

```
<< 250-xxx.internal.abc.com Hello [xxx.xx.xxx.xx]
250-SIZE 36700160
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250 XSHADOW

>> STARTTLS

<< 500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command

!! Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command
```

### What I tried part (I)

Somebody asked me to try MAIL_ENCRYPTION to null and dd(config('mail.encryption')), so the below is the answer:

Code:

```
    try { 
        Mail::send('emails.test', [], function ($m) {
        $m->from('xxx@client.com', 'Your Application')->to('me@me.com');
        dd(config('mail.encryption'));
        var_dump('executed');
    });
     } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage()); 
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
```

Result:
   `null`  was printed out The string `executed` was not.

### What I tried part (II):

explicitly use swiftmailer transport with encryption set to null

```
  try {
    // Create the Transport
    $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();

    $transport->setUsername('xxx@client.com')
    ->setPort(25)
    ->setHost('smtp.internal.client.com')
    ->setEncryption(null);

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
    $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));


    $message = new \Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject');
    $message->setFrom(['xxx@client.com' => 'John Doe']);
    $message->setTo(['me@me.com'])->setBody('Here is the message itself');

    // // Send the message
    $numSent = $mailer->send($message);
    } catch(\Swift_TransportException $e) {
        var_dump('test');
        var_dump($e->getMessage()); 
        var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
```

Result:

```
www-data@server:~/html/laravel-app$ php artisan email:send
string(4) "test"
string(127) "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx@client.com" using 0 possible authenticators"
string(2503) "#0 /var/www/html/a3qp/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(332): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport))
```

### What I tried Part (III):

Same as part II but set encryption to 'tls' explicitly. I get the same error message as the original one at the very top.

### What I tried Part (IV):

Someone asked me to take out the dd line in Part I This is what I got

```
string(8) "executed"
[Swift_TransportException]
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx@client.com" using 0 possible authenticators
```

**Update**

1. I am using SMTP to a MS Exchange server that is in my client's infrastructure. I have no access to that server's SMTP log, so it's hard to troubleshoot. The code is totally intranet. There is no access to outside internet service and I am not supposed to use mailgun or any other smtp cloud services to send client's transactional emails meant for internal consumption.
2. I have another code using a legacy cakephp 2 system that can work with the same SMTP mail server with no issues.
3. I have tested my laravel SMTP settings on a google mail. And it works fine.
4. My next step for troubleshooting is to see if it's swiftmailer or the rest of laravel where the issue lies. Hence this post.
5. Yes, I am trying to get hold of the IT team responsible for the Exchange server, but they are in another country. I am still trying though.
6. I know I am repeating point 2, but the comments suggest that this point is not clear enough. I am using the **exact same SMTP settings** on a legacy cakephp 2 system to send emails and there is no issue. Because I cannot get hold of the IT team responsible for the exchange server and plus the SMTP settings **do work** for another cakephp 2 system, I feel I should try to troubleshoot it on the laravel system to find out for sure.
7. I have tried PHP mail and sendmail by changing the .env file. I did not trigger any error messages but i also appear not to receive any emails.
8. Please see What I tried Part I, Part II, Part III, Part IV for details on code used to test the SMTP

Comment: https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/sending-emails-with-laravel-and-mailgun

Comment: You can use Mailgun: http://mailgun.com

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski see above to understand why I cannot. and why previously i used a different framework (cakephp 2) on the same smtp setup with no issue

Comment: SMTP is an industry standard protocol. If you're able to connect to Google via SMTP, but not to the Exchange server, that suggests it's more likely something to do with the Exchange server configuration, than SwiftMailer. Have you spoken with your client's IT team or whomever administers the Exchange mail server?

Comment: I am trying to get hold of the IT team responsible but it's difficult as they are located in another country. secondly, the *exact same SMTP* settings was okay in the legacy cakephp 2 system. So it's difficult for me to feel that the issue lies with the Exchange server. Does that help clarify the issue?

Comment: Not for me it doesn't I'm afraid. But I'm not well versed in mail server configuration. You set the same ports, encryption, auth details, from address, everything? Have you tried using sendmail or mail? If internal, you may not have the same issues with the emails being treated as spam.

Comment: @fubar
>You set the same ports, encryption, auth details, from address, everything? Yes I have.
 >Have you tried using sendmail or mail?
No, I have not. Given that I need to send out the email from the SMTP server in order to display the right FROM address, I am a bit disinclined to try sendmail (which if I read you correctly, is an internal service to the server my laravel is on, yes?)

Comment: Yes, it's a mail server hosted on the same server as your web server. And it's possible to spoof from addresses. Usually the problem comes with your email being marked as spam, but if you're not leaving the network, it may not be an issue. Just trying to suggest options for you.

Comment: I will give sendmail a shot and then update you here again. @fubar. Thank you.

Comment: @fubar I have tried PHP mail and sendmail. It looks like I don't even have an error message but I also did not receive emails.

Comment: You're attempting to use tls encryption, but the server has not responded with that command as being available. You need to turn off encryption. Do you have `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` set in your `.env` file? If you do a `dd(config('mail.encryption'))`, what is output (should be `null`).

Comment: Thanks @patricus. See above answer on What I tried Part I on what I got from your suggestion.

Comment: @KimStacks `dd()` stands for "dump and die", so it actually dies after it dumps the output. That is why "expected" never printed. It was just a quick test to make sure encryption was set to `null`. Retry part 1 with the `dd()` removed, and see if the email works.

Comment: @patricus did  it. See Part IV above for what I tried and got. I think the tls is absolutely essential. What you think?

Comment: @KimStacks The SMTP server you're attempting to connect to does not understand the `STARTTLS` command. That is the first issue you are running into, and why you must set the encryption option to `null`. Now it looks like swift mailer is attempting to authenticate, but from the `EHLO` response you've posted, this server does not allow authentication (no auth methods listed on the `250-AUTH` line). So, I'd say the next step is to set `MAIL_USERNAME=null` in your `.env` and try again. What does that give you?

Comment: @patricus so you mean set both the username and encryption to null?

Comment: @KimStacks Correct.

Comment: @patricus your solution worked on my localhost, and then what happened was that I also needed to change the `APP_URL` in `.env` on the server for it to work as well. Otherwise, it will just say successful, but no actual email was sent when I am using Laravel Mail class.

I be happy to mark your answer as correct and give you bounty as well if you can provide a solution before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SMTP server you're attempting to connect to does not understand the `STARTTLS` command. To prevent the `STARTTLS` command from being attempted, you must disable encryption by setting your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` environment variable to `null` in your `.env` file.

The next issue is that, according to the `EHLO` response, the SMTP server does not accept any authentication methods. If it did, the line `250-AUTH` would also include the methods it accepted (e.g. `250-AUTH PLAIN DIGEST-MD5`).

To prevent an authentication attempt, you must set your `MAIL_USERNAME` environment variable to `null` in your `.env` file.

To sum up, your `.env` file should have the following lines:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
```

That will disable tls encryption and disable authentication.

Comment: This solved my //Swift_TransportException
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "abc@abc.com" using 2 possible authenticators// issue. But when I do password reset, Im not getting any emails to my email account.Why?( no errors at the page)

Comment: Using Swift locally sending to Mailhog (a local SMTP w/web UI akin to MailTrap), this solved my issue! Thanks!